# Tesseract ocr for bengali language in vs C++

Tags: c++, tesseract

I'm working with [google tesseract ocr](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/). It is working for English language correctly. But for Bengali language it's giving garbage value. How can I do it coreectly? For clarification, I'm giving my code. I had downloaded from here [this](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe&) and installing it. During installation I've trained Bengali language. Plase help me

```
#include<baseapi.h>
#include <allheaders.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(void){

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI api;
    api.Init("", "ben", tesseract::OEM_DEFAULT);
    api.SetPageSegMode(static_cast<tesseract::PageSegMode>(7));
    api.SetOutputName("out");

    cout<<"File name:";
    char image[256];
    cin>>image;
    PIX   *pixs = pixRead(image);

    STRING text_out;
    api.ProcessPages(image, NULL, 0, &text_out);

    //cout<<text_out.string();
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("example.txt");
    myfile << text_out.string();
    myfile.close();
}
```

Comment: Can you try using the [parchit](https://code.google.com/p/parichit/) train data or [tesseractindic](https://code.google.com/p/tesseractindic/) and determine if the results are any way different?

Comment: Results are same. If you were working with hindi, you can also help me by sharing your idea. Thank you.

Comment: My experience is bengali language is, characters are indistinguishable because of `matra` . There are stylish ways of writing where a free form of a writing combines characters in a manner to show a matra continuation from the ending of an alphabet. I would suggest you is to start with a printed text and then graduate to different free form of bengali writings.Finally your mileage would vary based on the type of project you are working.

Comment: I'm trying with printed text. But after trained bengali data it's not working. Giving garbage value. I think it's font setting problem. May be I have to set font in code. It's my imagine only. I have found sole link UTF-8 or something. But can't get any answer.